# can i use "last" filter in jinja for dict object?

Tags: jinja2

```
messages = {
    '1': "hi i m here",
    '2': "how r u"
}
// in jinja template: 
{{ messages | last }}
```

I don't know what is the size of the `dict` that I am getting and I want to access its last element. Can i do this? I m getting an error on using this

```
return iter(reversed(seq)).next()
```

Comment: You should post your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a `dict` is not a sequence (it has no order), so the `last` filter will not work on it.  You should convert it to a sorted list before passing it to your template if the order is important, or pass the most recent message individually.

If you must do the sort in-place, you can use the `dictsort` filter to produce a sorted list of (key,value) pairs.